# Как работают форматы файлов

Tags: файлы, файловая-система, формат, байты

Меня очень интересует, каким образом хранятся данные, как их хранить и читать из файлов, которые при открытии текстовыми редакторами показывают байты, тот же sublime text показывает в таких файлах группы символов по 4 символа. Как пример, архивы, растровые изображения, музыка, .dat файлы и прочее. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: У каждого такого файла свой собственный формат. Но в целом это просто большой набор байт, составленный в опрделенном для формата порядке.

Comment: По 4 символа это для удобства, в самом файле разделения нет

Comment: вот а теперь сама суть вопроса - я могу сам тоже перевести в байты информацию, записать ее в файл, но ведь она будет просто как текст, тогда как записать байты, а не текст ?

Comment: В ячейках памяти компьютера есть состояние. Если конденсатор заряжен, то оно означает, что в бите единица. Если не заряжен то ноль. Состояние буквенное не бывает. Кто как посмотрит у кого буква, а у кого число. У каждого языка программирования есть свои операции записи. Но в основном принцип один : буква '0' и число 48 это одно и тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Создание нового файла происходит в логической файловой системе.

Файл состоит из нескольких частей. В файловой системе хранится логическая информация о файле (File Control Block) FCB (на рисунке показана часть FCB общая для разных ФС)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также FCB может содержать метаданные файла (атрибуты, время создания и пр.).

Следует различить тип файла с точки зрения ОС:

- Каталоги

  - Файлы
  - Символьные специальные файлы (моделирование последовательных устройств ввода-вывода)
  - Блочные специальные файлы (моделирование дисков)
  - Обычные файлы

    - Бинарные (исполнимые)
    - Текстовые

      - Текстовые
      - Типизированные (видео, архив)
      - Шелл-коды

И тип файла с точки зрения прикладной программы:

Тип файла с точки зрения прикладной программы это обычный файл, чаще текстовый (типизированный файл). Здесь тип файла (картинка, видео, файл программы, архив и т.п.) распознается либо по метаданным либо по сигнатуре в начале файла.

Например сигнатура [JPEG](https://www.ntfs.com/jpeg-signature-format.htm)

Сигнатура файла имеет широкое применение и существуют [стандартизированные сигнатуры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) для различных популярных форматов файлов.

Файл просто логическая единица, чтобы организовать набор данных.
Таким образом, область диска обозначается как принадлежащая файлу.

Файлы, как правило, имеют атрибуты, которые обычно включают в себя следующее:

- Имя файла
- Идентификатор
- Тип
- Расположение
- Размер
- Защита
- Время, Дата, UserID

Файлы часто имеют расширения, отделенные от имени файла точкой, например `fork.txt`.
Расширение `txt` сообщает нам некоторую информацию о файле - текстовый файл.

Это - в основном подсказки ОС или пользователю о том, что это за файл. 
В большинстве операционных систем любая программа может открывать произвольные файлы.
Расширение `.docx` является всего лишь предложением, чтобы его открывали программы обработки текста.

Операционные системы обычно позволяют установить программу по умолчанию для расширения: например, всегда открывать файлы `.docx` с помощью LibreOffice.

Методы доступа к файлу

*Последовательный доступ* простейший метод.

Информация в файле обрабатывается по порядку, один раздел за другим.
Большинство операций это чтение и запись.

Операции могут выглядеть примерно так: read\next переход к следующей записи и чтение.

Обычный вид доступа - *прямой доступ*

Любая часть файла может быть доступна в любое время.

Вместо того, чтобы читать следующий блок или переходить к следующему блоку, мы можем читать или искать произвольный блок.

Пример копирования файла в Linux

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int inputFd, outputFd, openFlags;
    mode_t filePerms;
    ssize_t numRead;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    if (argc != 3)
        printf("%s old-file new-file\n", argv[0]);

    /* Открываем входной и выходной файл */

    inputFd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (inputFd == -1)
        printf("Ошибка открытия файла %s\n", argv[1]);

    openFlags = O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC;
    filePerms = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP |
                S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;      /* rw-rw-rw- */
    outputFd = open(argv[2], openFlags, filePerms);
    if (outputFd == -1)
        printf("Ошибка создания файла %s\n", argv[2]);

    /* Перемещаем данные блоками пока файл не кончится */

    while ((numRead = read(inputFd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
        if (write(outputFd, buf, numRead) != numRead)
            printf("невозможно записать в файл\n");
    if (numRead == -1)
        printf("ошибка чтения\n");

    if (close(inputFd) == -1)
        printf("ошибка закрытия исходного файла\n");
    if (close(outputFd) == -1)
        printf("Ошибка закрытия копии файла\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```